# Как прописать условие для modx?

Tags: javascript, php, modx

Как можно прописать условие, что если фотографии загружены в блок "фото до/после" то показать блок, а если нет то скрыть. Вот такой код находится в шаблоне https://prnt.sc/nobxk9

Comment: Код лучше привести здесь в текстовом виде, чем на скриншоте да еще на постороннем сайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте модификатор вывода:

```
[[*main_slider:notempty=`тут весь ваш обведенный блок`]]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает! круто!